# Multithreading and ZMQ DEALER/REP hello world doesn't work

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

First of all my code (largely inspired from ZMQ doc http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:mtserver):

```
import zmq
import time
import sys
import threading

#SOCKET_NAME = "tcp://127.0.0.1:8000"
SOCKET_NAME = "inproc://mysocket"

def dealerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    socket.bind(SOCKET_NAME)
    time.sleep(12)
    socket.send("hello")
    socket.send("hello")
    print socket.recv()
    print socket.recv()
    socket.close()


def workerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(SOCKET_NAME)
    s = socket.recv()
    print s
    socket.send("world")

context = zmq.Context()

workers = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=workerRoutine, args=([context]))
    workers.append(worker) 
    worker.start()

dealerRoutine(context)

for worker in workers:
    worker.terminated = True

context.term()
```

I've tried this code with both inproc and tcp sockets.

- inproc gives an error when workers try to connect
- TCP just waits after the send on the dealer, no print appears from worker, no other message is received on dealer
- I've thought of the slow joiner problem and add a sleep (one before the workers to connect, and one before dealer's send()) : that just causes the inproc to behave the same as TCP does.

PS : I'm sorry for camelCase but I'm addicted to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work by:

- for the dealer, sending your message in multipart, the first part being an empty message, the second part being your message
- reduced the timer (that one didn't help though)

Here is the code:

```
import zmq
import time
import sys
import threading

SOCKET_NAME = "tcp://127.0.0.1:8000"
#SOCKET_NAME = "inproc://mysocket"

def dealerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    socket.bind(SOCKET_NAME)
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("hello")
    socket.send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("hello")
    print socket.recv()
    print socket.recv()
    socket.close()


def workerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(SOCKET_NAME)
    s = socket.recv()
    print s
    socket.send("world")

context = zmq.Context()

workers = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=workerRoutine, args=([context]))
    workers.append(worker) 
    worker.start()

dealerRoutine(context)

for worker in workers:
    worker.terminated = True

context.term()
```

Comment: Thanks I got help from minrk on the IRC dedicated to 0 MQ the problem was that multipart message. Readers might use send_multipart(['', 'hello']) which is equivalent to what you've done with the zmq.SNDMORE flag.

Comment: I think there's another bug in this code. The dealerRoutine needs to receive *twice* for everything sent to it. So, in this case, it needs 4 `print socket.recv()` statements... if you try it you'll see that it only prints "world" on the second and fourth prints. I haven't found where this is documented in ZMQ yet, though.