# Why do I need to receive twice for every message sent to a zmq.DEALER?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I setup a REP/DEALER connection in ZMQ and found that when REP sends one msg to DEALER, the latter must recv twice to get the message. **Why is this?**

The code to replicate this is a modified version of the code [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923314/1116674). Their code only receives once per worker, but I tested this and I only get one "world" back. I had to receive four times to get 2 "world"s back, as such:

```
import zmq
import time
import sys
import threading

SOCKET_NAME = "tcp://127.0.0.1:8000"
#SOCKET_NAME = "inproc://mysocket"

def dealerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    socket.bind(SOCKET_NAME)
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("hello")
    socket.send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send("hello")
    print "first msg", socket.recv()
    print "second msg", socket.recv()
    print "third msg", socket.recv()
    print "fourth msg", socket.recv()
    socket.close()


def workerRoutine(context):
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(SOCKET_NAME)
    s = socket.recv()
    print "worker received", s
    socket.send("world")

context = zmq.Context()

workers = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=workerRoutine, args=([context]))
    workers.append(worker) 
    worker.start()

dealerRoutine(context)

for worker in workers:
    worker.terminated = True

context.term()
```

Comment: I had a similar problem yesterday with Java and `inproc`...the DEALER must bind first and wait before the worker connects, otherwise, you get a strange error; are you ensuring that order?

Comment: yes, inproc has that limitation, from the zmq docs: "The inter-thread transport, inproc [...] has a specific limitation compared to tpc and icp: the server must issue a bind before any client issues a connect." However, here we're using tcp, and this doesn't have that limitation. From the docs: "We call this disconnected because ØMQ's tcp transport doesn't require that the endpoint exists before you connect to it. ". source: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Unicast-Transports

Comment: My apologies again, I see `inproc` is commented out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I RTFM and the answer is that: ZMQ msgs to and from REP sockets are contained in envelopes. So, under the hood, a REP expects a message with a delimiter and then the message content; then, it strips away the delimiter and returns *only the content* to the application. This is why the DEALER sends messages like this:

```
socket.send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
socket.send("hello")
```

, because REP expects that delimiter there that it will strip off and DEALER won't do it for us automatically.

Now, when REP sends a message back to the DEALER, the inverse is true. In the application, it looks like we're just sending the data without anything extra:

```
socket.send("world")
```

However, REP sockets add a delimiter in front so that the message is sent "in an envelope" just like it was received.

**So, why does DEALER need to receive twice?**

Because, unlike REP, DEALER will not handle delimiters implicitly. It keeps everything as-is. Therefore, since we know it is receiving from a REP socket, we can safely receive *twice*, one to remove the delimiter ourself, and another to actually get the data:

```
socket.recv() # discard delimiter
our_data = socket.recv()
```

sources:

- http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Extended-Reply-Envelope
- http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Recap-of-Request-Reply-Sockets
- http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-DEALER-to-REP-Combination